# What does net_error = -2 indicate for HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY event in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, cache-control

Saw net_error = -2 error in chrome://net-internals/#events while trying to troubleshoot why chrome is not using cached version of a file,  does any one know what -2 code means?

```
t=113683 [st= 0]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=113684 [st= 1]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=113684 [st= 1]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=1]
                      --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=113685 [st= 2]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=2]
t=113687 [st= 4]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=113687 [st= 4]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=113687 [st= 4]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=3]
t=113690 [st= 7]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                        --> source_dependency = 57257 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=113690 [st= 7]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=113690 [st= 7]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
```

Comment: Looks like a generic error, will have to look into the source to figure out what it means in HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  event context.

http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/net/base/net_error_list.h

// A generic failure occurred.
NET_ERROR(FAILED, -2)

Comment: I am getting this exact error on an XHR request in Chrome 43.0.2357.134 on Windows 7 only. Mac OS is fine. The XHR request is not loading.
t=59224 [st=1]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=59224 [st=1]      HTTP_CACHE_OPEN_ENTRY  [dt=0]
                    --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
t=59224 [st=1]      HTTP_CACHE_CREATE_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=59224 [st=1]      HTTP_CACHE_ADD_TO_ENTRY  [dt=0]
t=59224 [st=1]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=59224 [st=1]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=?]